# Validation of form multiple valid labels

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery validation plugin to validate a form. I have created following styling in css

```
label.valid {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(../images/form_tic.png) center center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    }

label.error {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(../images/form_cross.png) center center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    }
```

So what I want is whenever the field input is correct it shows a tickmark and wrong it shows cross.

Here is my js code below.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $('#commentForm').validate({
             success: function(label) {label.removeClass("error").addClass("valid")},
        rules: {
                cemail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                cname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                ccompany: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                },
                cphone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8,
                    number:true
                },
                csupplier: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                }                   
            }        
        });

    });        
    </script>
```

Now the problem is whenever I enter a field correctly, and move to next field, checkmark is shown but as soon as I return to the field again and type something for every alphabet or letter I type a label of valid class is added result in in as many ticks as I keep on typing.

Also if I remove the text all together from the field the valid class labels are not removed and error class label is shown. Here is an attached photo of it

[image]

Comment: label.removeClass("error").removeClass("valid").addClass("valid")

Comment: no it does'nt work same thing happens and even the cross does'nt show in error

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a couple years old, but I ran across this problem myself and found the solution. The problem is that jQuery Validate only removes the label with the class "error". Which means that you can't use `label.removeClass("error").addClass("valid")`. You can add a class like "valid" but you can not remove the class "error" without it stacking the label since it's looking for the corresposnding label with the class "error" to remove. Seems a little backwards to have a label with the both error and valid classes, but with appropriately arranged and styled css it doesn't become problem.

Comment: To give an exact answer: get rid of the part '.removeClass("error")' from your jQuery. Then move your css selectors so that 'label.valid' is after 'label.error' and you should be fine.